Any way to have a numeric keypad in a telegram bot chat?
I'm creating a telegram bot that can log vehicle consumption.
The user starts a new log with a command and replies to the bot with the requested info, at the end, everything is saved to a db.
The bot logic is quite easy:

send a message to the user requesting a specific value (money spent, amount of fuel, distance since last refill, ...)
wait for a textual reply
try to parse the reply as a number and continue with the next field

Since all the textual interactions are numeric values, I was trying to implement a numeric keyboard to speed up the logging process.
The only solution I found so far to get a numeric keyboard is this, but it sends a message with each digit, which is not what I'm looking for...
Is there any way (other than the previous solution and making a web app) to have a numeric keyboard in a telegram bot chat?

You could do something like showing some buttons as inline keyboards.

It's not what I was hoping for but this might work...
I would have to edit the previous message with each pressed button to get a feeback to the user, but it should be doable!
I will update on the outcome

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
